# Update GDAL in an Anaconda environment

Tags: gdal, anaconda, conda

I have a GDAL installed in an Anaconda environment:

```
(base) > conda create --name gdal_env
(base) > conda activate gdal_env
(gdal_env) > gdal_info --version 
GDAL 3.0.2, released 2019/10/28
```

this is an old version and I would like to update it to 3.1. I used conda update but it did not work and I am trying to avoid pip.

```
(gdal_env) > conda update gdal
...
(gdal_env) > gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.0.2, released 2019/10/28
```

It's already installed and it seems like there are no threads that discuss the update, only the installations.

How should I update my GDAL in an Anaconda environment?

Comment: Does `conda install gdal=3.1`  (or possibly `conda install -c conda-forge gdal=3.1`) do what you want?

Comment: @Jose it does not work. ```PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:```

Comment: @Jose with ```conda-forge``` channel apparently works! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned by @jose in the comment, use `conda-forge` channel when invoking `conda install`.

```
(base) > conda create --name gdal
(base) > conda activate gdal
(gdal) > conda install -c conda-forge gdal=3.1.1
(gdal) > echo check if gdal is installed
(gdal) > conda list | grep gdal
```